# Effect of a Lorentzian pulse on a non-resonant spin particle

Tags: radio-frequency, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I'm looking into rotation of a nuclear spin particle using a pulse with a Lorentzian lineshape. If the pulse has an area of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the nuclear spin frequency is on resonance with the pulse, the nucleus will be rotated by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. However, if the nuclear spin frequency is not on resonance with the pulse but is still overlapping (e.g. the nuclear spin frequency is at the half maximum of the pulse), it will be rotated by some angle $\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Is there some formula to determine the size of this angle as a function of frequency offset?